# Android stock browser: How to prevent double tap closing browser

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-browser

On a HTC Desire Z and a HTC Wildfire I'm seeing issues in the stock android browser where a double tap on any part of the web page crashes the stock browser.

I've tried preventing JavaScript from running and it still occurs.

I hooked the phone up to eclipse (I won't get into how that's done) and used logcat to take a look at what was happening and this mess was the result:

```
03-07 11:09:10.650: D/webview(23902): [WebView::UPDATE_SELECTION] ====== start
03-07 11:09:10.880: I/PluginManager(23902): PluginManager add: /system/lib/plugins/com.htc.flashliteplugin
03-07 11:09:10.880: I/PluginManager(23902): PluginManager add: /data/data/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib
03-07 11:09:10.880: I/webview(23902): doDoubleTap: /system/lib/plugins/com.htc.flashliteplugin
03-07 11:09:10.880: I/webview(23902): doDoubleTap: /data/data/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib
03-07 11:09:10.880: E/webview(23902): doDoubleTap hit!
03-07 11:09:10.890: D/skia(23902): [htcFlashPlugin::_pluginGetView] hitNode is NULL
03-07 11:09:10.890: D/skia(23902): [HTCWebCore::nativeSmartTouchUp] ==== [0x0]
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238): Build fingerprint: 'htc_wwe/htc_vision/vision:2.3.3/GRI40/192788.4:user/release-keys'
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238): pid: 23902, tid: 23902  >>> com.android.browser <<<
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000003a
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 7fffffff
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  r4 be9eccf4  r5 00000000  r6 be9ecd68  r7 0000000c
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  r8 ffffff24  r9 00000004  10 000000cf  fp 00000028
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  ip a873f7c0  sp be9ecc80  lr a858611f  pc ab17be1c  cpsr 60000010
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d0  434e0000c3858000  d1  4218000043280000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d2  3f8000003f800000  d3  428c0000428c0000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000043700000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d6  3f8000003f800000  d7  4080000043878000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  4362d96d4362d96d
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d10 43f1142f405a0a40  d11 0000000043f1142f
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d16 4070b00000000000  d17 4070b00000000000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d18 4065000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d20 3ff0000000000000  d21 8000000000000000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d22 c065000000000000  d23 0201000001030604
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d24 0003000700020006  d25 0003000700020006
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d26 00090011001c0014  d27 000c000900050004
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d28 002d0036003c0034  d29 3ff0000000000000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
03-07 11:09:10.991: I/DEBUG(1238):  scr 68000012
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):          #00  pc 0007be1c  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):          #01  lr a858611f  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): code around pc:
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): ab17bdfc 3c800000 e92d41f0 ed2d8b02 e1a05000 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): ab17be0c ee082a10 e24dd050 e1a04001 e3a01000 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): ab17be1c e5d0703a e5906004 ebfff960 e1d533b8 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): ab17be2c e7e170d7 e3130040 1a000034 eddf8a3b 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): ab17be3c eeb58a40 eef1fa10 03a01000 1a000028 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): code around lr:
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): a85860fc b00c6da0 bf00bd10 6e02b510 4300f06f 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): a858610c 429ab08c d1194604 2200a901 f5e36c40 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): a858611c ed94ee80 ed9d1a14 ee777a02 6c200a01 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): a858612c ee10aa0a f7ff1a90 980bff9d ee10f5e3 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): a858613c 0a10ee00 7ac0eefd 7a18edc4 b00c6e20 
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): stack:
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc40  00010008  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc44  be9ecc68  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc48  ab20d9ec  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc4c  0080a950  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc50  00889a78  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc54  ab1bade8  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc58  00000000  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc5c  ab17140c  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc60  00000124  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc64  be9ecee8  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc68  00911698  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc6c  000126e9  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc70  000126e9  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc74  00000000  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc78  df002777  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc7c  e3a070ad  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238): #00 be9ecc80  ab17a494  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc84  ab2111b8  
03-07 11:09:11.061: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc88  00000001  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc8c  00000000  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc90  00000000  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc94  ab17885c  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc98  be9ecdc4  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecc9c  00000000  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecca0  be9ecd98  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecca4  ab19a34c  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9ecca8  be9ecdc0  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9eccac  ab175e44  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9eccb0  be9eccd8  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9eccb4  be9ecdc0  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9eccb8  be9ecd98  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9eccbc  ab17b420  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9eccc0  009391bc  
03-07 11:09:11.071: I/DEBUG(1238):     be9eccc4  be9ecd44  
03-07 11:09:12.132: D/ConnectivityService(1332): getMobileDataEnabled returning false
03-07 11:09:12.402: W/ContentService(1332): binderDied() at ObserverNode name allowed_geolocation_origins
03-07 11:09:12.402: I/ActivityManager(1332): Process com.android.browser (pid 23902) has died.
03-07 11:09:12.402: I/WindowManager(1332): WIN DEATH: Window{409f71a0 com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity paused=false}
03-07 11:09:12.412: D/Zygote(1240): Process 23902 terminated by signal (11)
03-07 11:09:12.412: E/ActivityManager(1332): fail to set top app changed!
```

which seems to suggest it could be a flash issue (odd, as the page doesn't load flash at all) or a bug with the built in double-tap event, or some CSS or HTML element that doesn't work in the android stock browser.

Anyone know why this is happening or how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to help anyone else out with the same problem.

The answer was very hard to find but very easy to correct.

In my CSS I'd applied

```
body {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
}
```

to fix an issue with Google Fonts not rendering correctly. This sadly seems to be the culprit, as removing it immediately fixed the issue.